# current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell - different scenario - DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 DataGridView objects with the same five columns in each.  dgv1 has two of the columns' Visible property set to false.  dgv2 has all columns visible.  If I remove a DataGridViewRow from dgv1 and then add it to dgv2 using `dgv1.Rows.Remove(row)` and `dgv2.Rows.Add(row)`, then when I click on one of the cells in dgv2 that was NOT visible in dgv1, I get the error:

> "current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell"

I can check the `row.Cells[index].Visible` property after removing the DataGridViewRow from dgv1 and see that the two particular cells' Visible properties are set to false, as expected.  However, the `row.Cells[index].Visible` property is readonly, so I can't change it to true before adding the row to the dgv2.  And so when I add this row object to dgv2 which has all columns visible, I don't know how to prevent the above mentioned error from occurring every time I click on one of the cells that was hidden in dgv1 but is now visible in dgv2.

Does anyone know how to work around this situation, which is presumably a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest way but it does the job you need.I dont know what is your criteria for deleting a row so in my example i just picked a row(index 2 in my example),for your case its just switching to the row you need to remove:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[2].Clone();

int pivot = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewCell item in dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells)
{
    row.Cells[pivot].Value = item.Value;
    pivot++;
}
dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[2]);

dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Indeed, it looks like this should work.  I will report back a bit later when I have a moment to update my code.  Thanks for the idea.  Seems unfortunate that it has to involve creating a new row object, but realistically I'm not sure that there's another way.